# Remove social menu footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a website with wordpress, but I was asking me if it was possible to remove a "duplicate" menu --> I actually use Reyjavik theme, and created a child theme. It is possible to add a **Social menu** in the menu area. I implement a social menu and thought it was only present on the header part of the website. But no, it's also present in the footer..

[image]

I searched a lot on the internet, and saw that one way would be to write `diplay: none` but that it was not a good way for SEO.

Do you know how could I do to remove this footer link within my child theme without do a copy & modification of the entire main.php file please ? Is there a way like additional style.css file to block this button please ?

PS : It's not a widget

Thank you for your help !

Jerry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `visibility: hidden`.

`display:none` means that the element will not appear on the page at all (although you can still interact with it through the dom). There will be no space allocated for it between the other elements.

`visibility:hidden` means that unlike display:none, the element is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page. The element is rendered, it just isn't seen on the page.

Comment: thank you very much for your help ! And so it doesn't have consequence on SEO ? I didn't found how to hide only the footer one ; it's hidden also the top menu :(

Comment: To my knowledge it doesnt affect SEO. To hide only footer try adding `.site-footer` class before your CSS. So it would be like this: `.site-footer .social-links { visibility: hidden; }`. If it solves your problem, please mark this as answer.

Comment: Thank you @Andrey, works and affect only the footer :)

Answer (score 0):

Andrey's comment is worked well. The alternative way I would recommend is to remove source code by creating a child theme as you have done before. It will good for your performance which is better than overriding CSS.

There are a few steps

1. Copy **menu-social.php** from **templates/parts/menu** in Reyjavik theme
2. Create **templates** folder in child theme
3. Create **parts** folder in templates folder
4. Create **menu** folder in parts folder
5. Paste **menu-social.php** and edit source code (or remove it)

Hope it works to you!

Comment: Thank you Kopkap ! But in your solution I would have to copy all the **menu-social.php** and remove only the part which I don't want, right ?